# YAML pipeline does not have permissions to use agent pool

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In a new project, my long tested YAML build pipeline failed consistently with the following error:

```
##[error]Pipeline does not have permissions to use the referenced pool(s) BUILD. For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz.
```

The project has been set up the same way as previous projects.

How is the pipeline granted permission to use a given agent pool?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the default permissions have been changed for new projects making it necessary to explicitly grant pipelines in a project permission to use a given agent pool.

This is done in the **Project Settings** under **Agent pool**. Select the agent pool in question and go into the **Security** tab.

Either click the "+"-button to grant permission for specific pipelines or click the "three dot"-button and select "Open access" to grant all pipelines in the project permission to use the agent pool.